# spark streaming - NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks

Application Summary:-
Use spark streaming in databricks (scala) to receive messages from event hub and fetch files from s3

To get past serialization errors the below package(com.databricks.s3get) was defined and imported. The writeStream Method is as follows:-

```scala
import com.databricks.s3get._


val streamwriter = df
  .writeStream
  .queryName("stream")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/mnt/test/checkpoint")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("3 seconds"))
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch(
    (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => Try {
      
      batchDF.persist()
      
      val dataframe = batchDF.select("object", "batch")
      writeS3Object.getS3Object(dataframe)

      batchDF.unpersist()
      
    } match {
      case Success(_) =>
      case Failure(e) => {
        throw(e)
      }
    }
  )
```

Package cell:-

```scala
package com.databricks.s3get
//import all the necessary libraries
class fetchS3Object extends Serializable {
  //whatever is inside the "object fetchS3Object" is inside here ..ditto!
}

object fetchS3Object {
  //build client to connect to s3
  val AccessKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "My_Scope", key = "AccessKey-ID")
  val SecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "My_Scope", key = "AccessKey-Secret")
  val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey)
  val clientRegion: Regions = Regions.US_EAST_1
  private val s3Client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion(clientRegion)
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build()
  
  def getS3Object(df: DataFrame) {
    // execute foreach function to get s3 objects
    df.foreach(x => writeS3Object(x.getString(0), x.getString(1)))
  }
  
  def writeFunction(input: String, fileWrite: String) {
    //write s3 object content to file in datalake
    var fileWriter: FileWriter = null
    var bw: BufferedWriter = null
    val file = new File(fileWrite)
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
    bw.write(input)
    bw.close()
    fileWriter.close()
  }
  
  def getS3ObjectContentAsStream(bucketName: String, objectKey: String) ={
    //function to get s3 object content
    val contentStream = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, objectKey)
    contentStream.getObjectContent
  }
  
  def writeS3Object(s3ObjectName: String, batchname: String) {
    val s3FileName = s"${s3ObjectName}_.json"
    val inputS3Stream = getS3ObjectContentAsStream("myBucket",s3FileName)
    val inputS3String = IOUtils.toString(inputS3Stream, "UTF-8")
    val filePath = s"/dbfs/mnt/test/${batchname}/${s3FileName}"
    writeFunction(inputS3String, filePath)
  }
}
```

However on execution this error is thrown:-

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 161.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.5 in stage 161.0 (TID 3327) (10.21.132.64 executor 144): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.databricks.s3get.fetchS3Object$

    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1955)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:275)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:273)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:272)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:694)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1850)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1813)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$2(ResultTask.scala:65)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:65)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    
    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2783)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2724)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2724)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1260)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1260)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1260)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2991)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2932)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2474)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2457)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2495)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2514)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2539)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreach$1(RDD.scala:1017)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:1015)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$foreach$1(Dataset.scala:2920)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1(Dataset.scala:3804)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3802)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreach(Dataset.scala:2920)
        at com.databricks.s3get.fetchS3Object$.getS3Object(<notebook>:83)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf77157.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$tripsummarywriter$3(command-4241228593676676:36)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf7745.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$retry$1(command-4241228593676670:4)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf7745.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.retry(command-4241228593676670:4)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf7745.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.retry(command-4241228593676670:37)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf77157.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$tripsummarywriter$2(command-4241228593676676:10)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf77157.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$tripsummarywriter$1(command-4241228593676676:10)
        at $lineab81ab0d385746ac861c3adb69ddaf77157.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$tripsummarywriter$1$adapted(command-4241228593676676:8)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:608)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:606)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:606)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$4(MicroBatchExecution.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withSchemaEvolution(MicroBatchExecution.scala:649)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:241)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:366)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:268)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.databricks.s3get.fetchS3Object$
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1955)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:275)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:273)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:272)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:694)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1850)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1813)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$2(ResultTask.scala:65)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:65)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can this be resolved?

**Update without using classes and objects:-**

The dataframe consists of the two columns (s3ObjectName, batchName) with tens of thousands of rows

What is trying to be achieved:-
Retrieve objects from an S3 bucket in parallel using details from each row in the microbatch from the writeStream process using foreachPartition() or foreach() functions

```
// s3 connection details
def provides3Client(): AmazonS3 = {
    val AccessKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "My_Scope", key = "AccessKey-ID")
    val SecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "My_Scope", key = "AccessKey-Secret")
    val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey)
    val clientRegion: Regions = Regions.US_EAST_1
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion(clientRegion)
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build()
  }

dataframe.foreachPartition(partition => {
      //Initialize s3 connection for each partition
      val client: AmazonS3 = provides3Client()
      partition.foreach(row => {
        val s3ObjectName = row.getString(0)
        val batchname = row.getString(1)
        val inputS3Stream = client.getObject("s3bucketname", objectKey).getObjectContent
        val inputS3String = IOUtils.toString(inputS3Stream, "UTF-8")
        val filePath = s"/dbfs/mnt/pp-telematics-working-5/Sensors/s3response/test/${batchname}/${s3ObjectName}"
        var fileWriter: FileWriter = null
        var bw: BufferedWriter = null
        val file = new File(filePath)
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
        bw.write(inputS3String)
        bw.close()
        fileWriter.close()
        })
      })
```

The above process gives me Error: value foreach is not a member of Object

Comment: first question - if you're using notebooks, why do you need objects & classes? Have you checked this knowledge base article: https://kb.databricks.com/notebooks/common-errors-in-notebooks.html ?

Comment: The notebook was running into Serialization errors when I was doing df.foreach(x => writeS3Object(x.getString(0), x.getString(1))) without using classes and objects.
This databricks doc about best practices in structured streaming suggested using classes and objects https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/rdd-streaming/developing-streaming-applications.html

Comment: can you describe what you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: i just updated the purpose in the question